# Group by to include case statement inside SQL statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, pivot

I have a table which stores purchase info from sellers and table contains rating to every purchase out of 5 stars. I want to have output Group By sellers and Each sellers good(Above 3) and bad(Below 4) ratings count

```
PurchaseId  SellerId    PurchaseRating
1            ABC         2
2            ABC         5
3            DEF         1
4            XYZ         2
5            DEF         4
7            ABC         3

OUTPUT 
SellerId     TotalOrders   AvgRating    Above3*(4&5)  Below4*(1 to 3)
ABC           3             3.3        1              2
DEF           2             2.5        1              1
XYZ           1              2         0              1
```

For first 3 columns I am getting result using this

```
Select SellerId, Count(P.Id) TotalOrders, Avg(PurchaseRating) AvgRating, 
CASE WHEN P.PurchaseRating >= 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Above3*(4&5)
 from 
  [dbo].[AmazonAbeOrdersPurchaseInfo] P 
   Where PurchaseRating is not null
  Group by P.SellerId
  order by TotalOrders desc
```

Unable to identify how to include case in group by clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to do conditional aggreation. The important thing is that you want the conditional expression *inside* the aggregate function:

```
select 
    sellerId,
    count(*) totalOrders,
    avg(purchaseRating) avgRating,
    sum(case when purchaseRating > 3 then 1 else 0 end) above3,
    sum(case when purchaseRating < 4 then 1 else 0 end) below4
from [dbo].[AmazonAbeOrdersPurchaseInfo]
where purchaseRating is not null
group by sellerId
order by totalOrders desc
```